# Ошибка установки wordpress на open server

Tags: wordpress, openserver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая ошибка, когда пытаюсь установить WP на локальный сервер. Когда создавал пользователя в PHPmyAdmin указывал там галочку что бы создавалась БД с таким же именем, как у юзера. В итоге получилось

```
// ** Параметры MySQL: Эту информацию можно получить у вашего хостинг-провайдера ** //
/** Имя базы данных для WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'mtext');

/** Имя пользователя MySQL */
define('DB_USER', 'mtext');

/** Пароль к базе данных MySQL */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dvhjCfWlhqTwVQF9');

/** Имя сервера MySQL */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Кодировка базы данных для создания таблиц. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** Схема сопоставления. Не меняйте, если не уверены. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Но выдает ошибку, по какой причине такое может происходить?
Когда гуглил писали, что может быть MySQL не включено, тогда возникает вопрос как включить MySQL на OpenServer'e

Comment: Ошибку предлагаешь угадать?

Comment: @SeVlad, я в самом начале вопроса прикрепил скриншот ошибки.

Comment: А что, текстом нельзя написать? Нафига картинки букв? (я их действительно не увидел) Ошибка означает что в конфиге указаны либо не те данные, либо база не запущена.

Comment: База данных `mtext` должна быть создана и юзер `mtext` должен иметь к ней права записи/удаления и пр.

Comment: @SeVlad, Я это и загуглить мог, что я и сделал. Пароль и логин правильные 100%, бд создана с таким же именем. Как запустить БД, возможно она не запущена.

Comment: Это ты так думаешь, что всё правильно сделал. Других причин не коннекта к базе нет.

Comment: @SeVlad, так я спрашиваю как включить MySQL на OpenServer'e

Comment: Нет, ты спрашиваешь о причинах ошибки. А "как запустить" - это уже другой вопрос и к ВП отношения не имеет. (хотя скорее всего он у тебя запущен)

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте, есть ли эта проблема в wp-admin.
2. Попробуйте добавить в корень вашей темы файл test.php к примеру
   и добавить в него следующий код :

Вместо «пользователь» и «пароль» укажите свои данные для подключения к базе данных.
3. Есть ещё вариант подключиться к базе с помощью root/admin учётки

```
<?php 
    $resource = mysql_connect('localhost', 'пользователь', 'пароль');
    if (!$resource) {
    die('Ошибка при подключении: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 
    echo 'Подключено успешно!'; 
    mysql_close($resource);
    ?>
```